# Rename tag [prismatic-schema] to [plumatic-schema]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Prismatic Schema has been renamed to Plumatic Schema for several years. Is it possible to rename the Stack Overflow tag from [prismatic-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prismatic-schema) to [plumatic-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plumatic-schema)? Or, at least deprecate [prismatic-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prismatic-schema) and add a new tag [plumatic-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plumatic-schema).

The current GitHub project: https://github.com/plumatic/schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonable for the tag name to match the current name of the product, so this is now done.

**[plumatic-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plumatic-schema)** is the master tag, and [plumatic-schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plumatic-schema) exists as a synonym of that.

I also modified the tag wiki excerpt.